# JQuery UI Tooltip: Have different image per tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am kind of new to JavaScript so please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to display a different image for each tool tip. JQuery UI has it setup so the text inside is the name of the image.

Check out my code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tooltip" class="option-child"><a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="The Title" data-geo="Rochester" href="#" >• 1 layer of Rain on all windows and glass</a></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $( document ).tooltip({
        //items: "a, [data-geo], [title]",
        items: "a",
        position: {
          my: "left center-29",
          at: "right+10 center+18"
        },
        content: function() {

                var element = $( this );

                if ( element.is( "[data-geo]" ) ) {
                  var text = element.text();
                  return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
                    "' src='http://www.sample.com/img/tooltip/" +
                    text + ".jpg" + "'>";
                }

                if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                  return element.attr( "title" );
                }

                if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
                  return element.attr( "alt" );
                }
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: You are generating the `img` element's `src` attribute based on the text. Based on the conditional statement, I think you want to generate it based on the `[data-geo]` attribute... replace `text` in the `src` attribute with `$(this).attr('data-gep')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your tooltip selector is `items: "a"` then following statement will never execute.

```
if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
    return element.attr( "alt" );
}
```

**Solution:**

If you want to add tooltip to all `a` & `img` tag with or without `[data-geo]` try out following js.

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: "a,img",
    position: {
        my: "left center-29",
        at: "right+10 center+18"
    },
    content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if(element.is( "[data-geo]" )){
            return '<img class="map" alt="'+ $(this).data('geo') +'"  src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/'+ $(this).data('geo') +'.jpg" />';
        }

        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
            return element.attr( "title" );
        }

        if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
            return element.attr( "alt" );
        }
    }
});
```

I have also added html to cover all possible variant.

```
<div id="tooltip" class="option-child">
    <a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="The Title" data-geo="Rochester" href="#" >• 1 layer of Rain on all windows and glass</a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="sports image">
</div>
<a id="ceramic-pro-rain" title="The Title" href="#" >• Link without data-geo</a>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jqd5t58t/2/)

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!